# Object transform rotation around correct pivot, but wrong pivot after colliding

Tags: unity, rotation

I'm messing around a bit trying to create a table football table. So this involves create rods with players on them. The rod should be free to rotate around the Z axis with the players moving around the rods Z axis. I created a parent object for the rod with players to do any transforms on. I made sure that the pivot point is in the center of the rod so that rotating along the Z axis of the game object keeps the rod in its position while rotating. This worked as shown in the first picture, the object position remains unchanged while rotating.
[image]

The problem comes in when I run the game and have a ball collide with the 'player', this starts the player and rod spinning, but not around the right pivot point. The rod now moves in a circular/eliptical pattern. I checked that the rotation isn't happening around the center point either and it isn't. It rotates around an axis somewhere between the center point and the pivot point. Am I doing something wrong or am I tackling this from the complete wrong angle completely?

Comment: Have you tried using a hinge joint on the axis you want to control, or setting the center of mass to lie on that axis?

Comment: @DMGregory The hinge point did the trick! Thank you!

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please post an answer illustrating/explaining how you solved it (eg. what hinge joint settings you used)